# select columns sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im new using sql.

How should i say to sql extract only columns timestamp with zone. Like i did below for my two columns manually.

--query--

```
SELECT_TIMESTAMPTZ_columns="""
SELECT date11 AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Madrid' as date11, date22 AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Madrid' as date22
FROM {table} """
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: In SQL query you need to specify the names of each one of the columns you want to retrieve. Alternatively you can retrieve the table structure, inspect the list of columns, their data types, assemble a dynamic SQL statement, and then run it. Possible, but it's a lot of work. What's the specific use case for your question?

Comment: i need to extract only columns timestamp with zone for each self table. @TheImpaler